# How to handle non-ASCII Characters in Java while using PDPageContentStream/PDDocument

Tags: java, pdf, jsf, unicode, character-encoding

I am using [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to create PDF from my web application. The web application is built in Java and uses JSF. It takes the content from a web based form and puts the contents into a PDF document.

*Example*: A user fill up an inputTextArea (JSF tag) in the form and that is converted to a PDF. I am unable to handle non-ASCII Characters.

How should I handle the non-ASCII characters or atleast strip them out before putting it on the PDF. Please help me with any suggestions or point me any resources.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you know whether the data is corrupted on its way into the web app or on its way into the PDF?

Comment: Have you tried setting a correct encoding for your web form and your PDF generator ? (besides, how is your PDF generated ?)

Comment: The data is not corrupted but if someone copies the content from MSWord and tries to paste it in the text area, it might not like it.

Comment: @Riduidel I haven't tried to set any encoding to the web form, can you suggest how I can do that? Thanks

Comment: You need to be more clear about the problem. Is the data corrupted *before* or *after* converting to PDF? Just print the submitted data to stdout/log/console before converting to PDF.

Comment: The data gets corrupted before converting to PDF in some cases. My first step is to fill up the inputTextArea, then go to a confirm page using a button in the first page. During this phase the data gets corrupted. example : ' gets changed to ¿

Comment: 2nd case is that when the data gets passed well in the previous comment's step, its gets corrupted after converting to the pdf. I am facing both the problems, so can you please suggest how I should use character-encoding

Comment: Are you using JSF on JSP or Facelets? Edit: OK, as per your question history you seem to be using JSF on JSP. That's the culprit here.

Comment: Ya you are right I am using JSF over JSP instead of Facelets!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using JSF on JSP instead of Facelets (which is implicitly already using UTF-8), do the following steps to avoid the platform default charset being used (which is often ISO-8859-1, which is the wrong choice for handling of the majority of "non-ASCII" characters):

1. Add the following line to top of all JSPs:

   ```
   <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
   ```

   This sets the response encoding to UTF-8 *and* sets the charset of the HTTP response content type header to UTF-8. The last will instruct the client (webbrowser) to display and submit the page with the form using UTF-8.
2. Create a [`Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) which does the following in `doFilter()` method:

   ```
   request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   ```

   Map this on the `FacesServlet` like follows:

   ```
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>nameOfYourCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
       <servlet-name>nameOfYourFacesServlet</servlet-name>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```

   This sets the request encoding of all JSF POST requests to UTF-8.

This should fix the Unicode problem in the JSF side. I have never used PDFBox, but since it's under the covers using iText which in turn should already be supporting Unicode/UTF-8, I think that part is fine. Let me know if it still doesn't after doing the above fixes.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)