# java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

In my android application,i calling one webservice and it is returning one jsonobject.In device i getting one response like this..

```
"{  \"Time_Stamp\" : \"10/10/2012 4:26 PM\",  \"records\" : [ {    \"'Name'\" : \"'LD-00000002'\",    \"'Appointment_Date_Time'\" : \"'null'\",    \"'Phone'\" : \"'9909955555'\",    \"'Home_Country_Address'\" : \"'null'\",    \"'Occupation'\" : \"'null'\",    \"'SR_Appointment_Status'\" : \"'Open'\",    \"'Id'\" : \"'a0OE0000001iLynMAE'\",    \"'SR_Appointment_Comment'\" : \"'testing'\",    \"'ProductsOfInterest'\" : \"'null'\",    \"'ActivityName'\" : \"'Sales'\",    \"documentsList\" : [ ]  }, {    \"'Name'\" : \"'LD-00000002'\",    \"'Appointment_Date_Time'\" : \"'null'\",    \"'Phone'\" : \"'9909955555'\",    \"'Home_Country_Address'\" : \"'null'\",    \"'Occupation'\" : \"'null'\",    \"'SR_Appointment_Status'\" : \"'Open'\",    \"'Id'\" : \"'a0OE0000001iLynMAE'\",    \"'SR_Appointment_Comment'\" : \"'testing'\",    \"'ProductsOfInterest'\" : \"'null'\",    \"'ActivityName'\" : \"'Sales'\",    \"documentsList\" : [ {      \"numberOfImages\" : 3,      \"Name\" : \"new document\",      \"Mandatory\" : false,      \"FilePath\" : null,      \"Category\" : null    } ]  } ]}"
```

i trying convert it into an object like this

```
  JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(objMngr.getResponse());
```

when converting it throwing one exception "java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"...below is the exact exception that it is throwig ..What is the reason and how can i solve this issue??

```
 {  "Time_Stamp" : "10/10/2012 4:26 PM",  "records" : [ {    "'Name'" : "'LD-00000002'",    "'Appointment_Date_Time'" : "'null'",    "'Phone'" : "'9909955555'",    "'Home_Country_Address'" : "'null'",    "'Occupation'" : "'null'",    "'SR_Appointment_Status'" : "'Open'",    "'Id'" : "'a0OE0000001iLynMAE'",    "'SR_Appointment_Comment'" : "'testing'",    "'ProductsOfInterest'" : "'null'",    "'ActivityName'" : "'Sales'",    "documentsList" : [ ]  }, {    "'Name'" : "'LD-00000002'",    "'Appointment_Date_Time'" : "'null'",    "'Phone'" : "'9909955555'",    "'Home_Country_Address'" : "'null'",    "'Occupation'" : "'null'",    "'SR_Appointment_Status'" : "'Open'",    "'Id'" : "'a0OE0000001iLynMAE'",    "'SR_Appointment_Comment'" : "'testing'",    "'ProductsOfInterest'" : "'null'",    "'ActivityName'" : "'Sales'",    "documentsList" : [ {      "numberOfImages" : 3,      "Name" : "new document",      "Mandatory" : false,      "FilePath" : null,      "Category" : null    } ]  } ]} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: First validate your json in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Because it is not valid json response. Do what hardik joshi suggested.i think \ is problem . Remove \ from your json response.

Comment: if you look that exception,u can see it is converted to a proper json..

Comment: @vivek, the first string (the one with the backslashes), is that what you get from the server? Or have you escaped it to be a java string?

Comment: The server response seems weird even if you replace \" with " (and remove the surrounding quotes. Mane of the fields have double quotes. Even though JSON allows ' inside the strings, it is highly unlikely that this is what's intended. Did you write the server your self? That is where you need to start. Can you supply code for the server?

Comment: surprising thing is,in that exception message showing a valid json

Comment: `"'Name'"` --> are you sure it should not be `"Name"`?

Comment: removed single quotes..still it is not working

Answer (score 1):

try

```
  JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(objMngr.getResponse().toString().replace("\\", " "));
```

Your jsonString seems allright. However your response type may not be string. Try it.
The problem is with already escaped inverted commas sent by the server.

Comment: I made changes to my answer, try it now.

Comment: i already tried this one..even tried to remove hidden characters..still not working

Comment: if u look that error description,it is saying "of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject".But json string that appearing in error description is a valid json string.

Comment: I know. I understand and myself have validated the string you have mentioned. Do you have access to server?

Comment: is anything to change from server,then i need to contact my client

Comment: is any chance that it is appending any hidden characters??

Comment: well I don't have much expertise in this area, but there may be a EOF character or some such charachter that is not seen. If this is the case you may want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186192/how-to-handle-non-ascii-characters-in-java-while-using-pdpagecontentstream-pddoc

Answer (score 0):

First convert your response to a **String** then try to create a **JSONObject**

Comment: if your objMngr.getResponse() returns a valid Json format String then there should be no problem in creating json object.......

Answer (score 0):

I think, getResponse() is already string but response isn't valid JSON.If response isn't string,you can convert string with toString() method.

Answer (score 0):

It seem there are some hidden characters on your string.
Try this

```
return new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have dumped object to JSON string twice on server-side.

object --dumps()--> json string --dumps()-> one string in json

So you should remove the second dumping.

Otherwise you can unescape your string this way [How to unescape a Java string literal in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java).

The first way is better and easier i think.